# Socialcast - login with PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to get access to SocialCast's API from PHP.
They have just one example, done with curl:

```
# Curl Example
curl -X POST -d 'password=demo&amp;amp;amp;email=emily@socialcast.com' -v https://demo.socialcast.com/api/authentication.xml
```

How do I perform the login with PHP?

Here is the API documentation:
http://developers.socialcast.com/api-documentation/http-basic-authentication/#authentication_api_create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use php curl wrapper http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Something like this:

```
 $ch = curl_init("https://demo.socialcast.com/api/authentication.xml");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password=demo&amp;amp;amp;email=emily@socialcast.com");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
 $resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I've tried it, but $resp is empty. I've checked and I do have CURL installed.

Comment: OK, I managed to get error from CURL and it says Curl error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, so I guess that is the problem.

Comment: works now, I had to bypass SSL check, not ideal, but solves the problem. Found the solution here: http://ademar.name/blog/2006/04/curl-ssl-certificate-problem-v.html